# How can i change the direction of the light effect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To add a new bool variable that will use as flag between two directions forward and backward.

In the top of the script:

```
public float delay = 0.1f;

private Renderer[] renderers;
private float lastChangeTime;
private int greenIndex = 0;
private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
```

In the Start

```
void Start()
{
  LightsEffect();
}
```

Inside the Update

```
void Update()
{
  // Change color each `delay` seconds
        if (Time.time > lastChangeTime + delay)
        {
            lastChangeTime = Time.time;

            // Set color of the last renderer to red
            // and the color of the current one to green
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.red;
            greenIndex = (greenIndex + 1) % renderers.Length;
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
        }
}
```

And the LightsEffect method

```
private void LightsEffect()
    {
        renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
        }

        // Set green color to the first one
        greenIndex = 0;
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
    }
```

What i want to do is to use a flag to change the light movement direction.

Comment: Get the light game object programatically, and set the localRotation to be 180 degrees around the Y-Axis. This should make your light point in the opposite direction of where it was pointing originally. Use the boolean to determine whether to point it 0 around the Y or 180 from its original angle..

Comment: @Brandon Thanks solved it also by reversing the renderers array.  if (changelightsdir == true) { Array.Reverse(renderers); changelightsdir = false; }